# extending httpservlet on google app engine leaks requests

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

I'm baffled by this problem I encountered on Google App Engine.

I created several servlets, so I created a base class to do some basic repeated work. Like this:

```
public class MyBase extends HttpServlet {

      protected String someValue1;
      protected String someValue2;

      protected void setup(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)   {

         someValue1 = req.getParameter("paramName1");
         someValue2 = req.getParameter("paramName2");

}
```

and the servlet:

```
public class MyServlet extends MyBase {



    @Override
    public void doGet(final HttpServletRequest req,
                      final HttpServletResponse resp)  {

         super.setup(req, resp); 
         doWork(someValue1);
         doOtherWork(someValue2);

}
```

simple enough - this normally works perfectly and when running on a local server any amount of load testing works just fine. Also, testing on GAE works on test instances.  On my production instance, and only on production, with 1000's of simultaneous users the value of someValue1 and someValue2 become the requests of two different users!  Servlets will work 99% of the time, 1 out of 100 requests end up with parameters from different requests. Makes no sense but it's happening.

This is obviously a simplified version of the actual code, but I've reproduced it using integration tests.

Perhaps i'm missing some nuance about extending httpservlet?

Answer (score 2):

Using HttpServlet, it is better not to use instance variable, because the HttpServlet is reused between session.

It is usually for a Java EE container to create only 1 instance of MyServlet and create a thread  for each request received from client running `doService` -> `doGet`

To quick fix solve your problem, either

```
@Override //performance suffers greatly.
    public sychronized void doGet(final HttpServletRequest req,
                      final HttpServletResponse resp)  {
```

Or use `resp.setAttribute();`