# how to share value into a void

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, pdf

I have java class like below,I want to send the value from SENDINTOVOID variable into variable(GETVALUE) in void doGet

```
@WebServlet("/wodigital.pdf")
    @Controller
    public class installasi extends HttpServlet{

    //----------------------------------------------------------

        @RequestMapping(value = "/detail-installasi-teknikalsuc/{id_istlsi_tkn}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String detlapo(@PathVariable("id_istlsi_tkn") int id_istlsi
            , Map<String, Object> map) {
        RestTemplate tmp = new RestTemplate();
        String url = gt + "/ins-server-insta/ins-list-"+id_istlsi+"-insta-installasi";
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));


    tmp.getMessageConverters().add(new mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
            installasimodel res = tmp.getForObject(url,installasimodel.class);
    String SENDINTOVOID = res.getFoto_istlsi();
    System.out.println("foto :"+res.getFoto_istlsi());
    System.out.println("ttd :"+res.getTtd_istlsi());

        map.put("userdata", res);
    return "teknikal/detailinstasuc";
    }
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException { 
        String GETVALUE ="";
        System.out.println("value from  :");
        File file = new File("/opt/tomcat/file/upload/vendor/"+GETVALUE);
        response.setHeader("Content-Type",    getServletContext().getMimeType(file.getName()));
        response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"WO_Digital.pdf\"");
        Files.copy(file.toPath(), response.getOutputStream());
        }
       }
```

what should I change ?

Comment: You cannot return a value into `void`. So either you change the signature of `doGet` or you put the desired result into a new member of your object.

Comment: can you give an example ?

Comment: for the member object, do like here in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21533321/extending-httpservlet-on-google-app-engine-leaks-requests with `someValue1`.